# How to use long data for boxplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to create 3 boxplots for Depression scores for 3 groups, organised as long data in my table as below:

```
   Ppt_num Depression_score Group   Age Gender
     <dbl>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1       1                8     1    32      1
 2       2                4     1    45      2
 3       3               24     1    18      2
 4       4               11     1    45      1
 5       5               13     1    25      2
 6       6               14     1    67      2
 7       7               16     1    43      2
 8       8               11     1    25      1
 9       9                3     1    55      1
10      10               21     1    70      2
# ... with 80 more rows
```

When I use:

```
boxplot <- ggplot(mini, aes(x = Group, y = Depression_score, fill=Group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

It comes out with 1 boxplot instead of 3 and with the x-axis being labelled as 1.5, 2.0, 2.5.

When I then try:

```
boxplot<- ggplot(mini, aes(x = Group, y = Depression_score, fill=Group)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(~Group)
```

I successfully get 3 boxplots but as well as being separated by Group number (1, 2, 3) at the top, on the x-axis of each boxplot there's 1, 2, 3 as well so the first one is to the left above 1, the second in the middle above 2 and the third to the right above 3 which looks a little weird.

How can I get the boxplots to be separated like they are with facet_grid but not be divided twice?

Comment: Try `ggplot(mini, aes(x = factor(Group), y = Depression_score, fill = factor(Group))) + geom_boxplot()`. This turns the X axis elements into factors and should separate them.

Comment: The sample of data you included only has observations of group 1, so we won't be able to recreate the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same colors as your `facet_wrap`, you need to add `group=Group` to `aes`.

```r
data.table::fread("Ppt_num Depression_score Group   Age Gender
                         1                8     1    32      1
                         2                4     1    45      2
                         3               24     1    18      2
                         4               11     2    45      1
                         5               13     2    25      2
                         6               14     2    67      2
                         7               16     3    43      2
                         8               11     3    25      1
                         9                3     3    55      1
                        10               21     3    70      2") -> dt1


mini <- dplyr::as_tibble(dt1)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mini, aes(x = Group, y = Depression_score, fill=Group, group=Group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]